# payara 4.1.1.171 :: ecliselink jpa issue with case when condition

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, payara

On payara JPA named query with CASE and WHEN condition causes illegal argument exception. This was working fine with glassfish3.

EclipseLink bug id https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462663

Payara Github https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1941

Any help ?

Exception is as below

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.invokeConstructor(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:471)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQueryResult.buildResult(ReportQueryResult.java:122)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQueryResult.(ReportQueryResult.java:79)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.buildObject(ReportQuery.java:598)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.buildObjects(ReportQuery.java:649)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:852)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)

Comment: we all search errors in compilers, servers etc, not in own code. Whre is Your fragment?